# Find unofficial languages of that country using SPARQL

Tags: sparql

I need to find all languages spoken in countries that are not official languages of that country. I found out how to find the number of spoken languages in a country and also the number of official languages in a country, but I need to merge it and have a query that substracts the official languages to all spoken languages in a country. Does anybody know how I can use "MINUS" on two "COUNT" methods using SPARQL?

[Here is how I got the number of official languages in a country:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpLY9.png)

```
"""
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT ?country (COUNT(?officialLanguage) AS ?nrOfLanguages)
WHERE {
  ?country a dbo:Country .
  ?country dbo:officialLanguage ?officialLanguage. 
}
GROUP BY ?country 
HAVING(COUNT(?officialLanguage) > 1)
"""
```

[And here is how I got the spoken languages in a country:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7z7g.png)

```
"""
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT ?country (COUNT(?language) AS ?nrOfLanguages)
WHERE {
  ?country a dbo:Country .
  ?country dbo:language ?language. 
}
GROUP BY ?country 
HAVING(COUNT(?language) > 1)
"""
```

[What I need to find out is a way to do something like this: (that works oc)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1p9lM.png)

```
"""
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT ?country (COUNT(?language) AS ?nrOfLanguages) (COUNT(?officialLanguage) AS ?nrOfofiLanguages)
WHERE {
  ?country a dbo:Country .
  ?country dbo:language ?language. 
  { COUNT(?language) } MINUS { COUNT(?officialLanguage)}
}
GROUP BY ?country 
HAVING(COUNT(?language) > 1)
"""
```

Comment: `PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT ?country (COUNT(?language) AS ?nonOfficialLanguages)
WHERE {
  ?country a dbo:Country .
  ?country dbo:language ?language. 
  FILTER NOT EXISTS {?country dbo:officialLanguage ?language} 

}
GROUP BY ?country 
HAVING(COUNT(?language) > 1) 
` gives you the number of languages not being official language

Answer (score 0):

[`MINUS`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#neg-minus) is not used for subtracting numbers, but for excluding triples from the result. To subtract numbers, `-` gets used (e.g., in `SELECT`).

Instead of counting and subtracting (which relies on the data to specify all official languages also as `dbo:language`), you can use `FILTER NOT EXISTS`:

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT DISTINCT ?country ( COUNT(DISTINCT ?language) AS ?languagesWithoutOfficialLanguages )
WHERE {
  ?country a dbo:Country .
  ?country dbo:language ?language .
  FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?country dbo:officialLanguage ?language . }
} 
GROUP BY ?country
ORDER BY DESC(?languagesWithoutOfficialLanguages)
```

This query finds a country’s languages that are

1. a value of `dbo:language`,
2. AND NOT a value of `dbo:officialLanguage`.

Note that the query will only list countries that have at least one `dbo:language` value. To include countries without any value, you can use `OPTIONAL`:

```
OPTIONAL { ?country dbo:language ?language . }
```